# Visual Studio 08: Set a file-level breakpoint?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a file with 13.4K LOC. I would like to set a breakpoint that will be hit if any of the methods in the file are called. Is this possible? (Going through and marking them all myself would be a huge pain.)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Visual Studio macro to add a breakpoint at the beginning of each method in the file.

A macro would look something along the lines of this:

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub AddBreakpointForCurrentMethod()
        Dim textSelection As EnvDTE.TextSelection
        Dim codeElement As EnvDTE.CodeElement

        textSelection = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection
        Try
            codeElement = textSelection.ActivePoint.CodeElement(vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction)
            If Not (codeElement Is Nothing) Then
                DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add(Line:=codeElement.StartPoint.Line, File:=DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName)
            End If
        Catch
            MsgBox("Add error handling here.")
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

To solve the problem in the long run you might consider refactoring your code into smaller units that can be handled more easily.